# Waldorf Blofeld Firmware Recovery on a bricked unit

Tags: midi, synthesizer, hardware, digital

I recently tried updating my Waldorf Blofeld desktop synth to the latest firmware and it bricked.

I performed a rescue on the unit and then loaded the firmware again, but now there is no sound. After loading the firmware again along with sound banks, I get a "bad dsp" error which goes away but the encoders don't work.

I've given up on Waldorf support and am wondering if anyone has an earlier version of the firmware (not available on Waldorf site)... or should I just scrap it for parts?